# How does crop video by touch in android?

Tags: android, video, touch, crop, android-videoview

I need to crop(not trim) the video in my app.The crop can be square or rectangular form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/crust87/Android-VideoCropView

Using this library we can crop video

Answer (score 0):

You should use fenster android library for playing video. This library provides support scale type 'crop'.

https://github.com/malmstein/fenster

```
<com.malmstein.fenster.view.FensterVideoView
  android:id="@+id/play_video_texture"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:scaleType="crop" />
```